# Attention: Unsupported Video Configuration Detected

Tags: boot, graphics-card

I am working with a Dell Optiplex 390 tower running Windows 8. I connected it to a monitor via a VGA cable. The monitor also has a USB cable; I have the same problem whether I use the USB cable or not. (Unfortunately, the monitor doesn't have model number information on it anywhere, so I can't give you any more information about it.)

When I turn the computer on, I get the following message before boot finishes:

> Attention: Unsupported Video Configuration Detected
>
> Action is Required
>
> The computer has an add-in graphics card, but the monitor cable is plugged into the integrated video connector. [newline sic]
> To attach the monitor cable to the add-in graphics card:
>
> 1. Shut down the computer.
> 2. Plug the monitor cable into the add-in graphics card connector.
>    This may require a video adapter or video adapter cable.
>    (provided with the system)
> 3. Turn on the computer.
>
> This message should not appear after completing these steps.
> For more information or help, please refer to the system documentation.
>
> To continue press F1 key
> To change setup option press F2 key
> To run onboard diagnostics press F5 key

Researching this message, some people have fixed this by going into the BIOS settings to set which video card to prefer. Unfortunately, there are no such options in the BIOS settings for this computer. Others have solved it by purchasing additional hardware or replacing the graphics cards. I would like to avoid doing that if I can.

If I press the F1 key, the computer works perfectly fine. I'm setting up a computer in a lab that university students will use, though, so I don't want to keep showing them this intimidating message.

Are there any software solutions to this problem? If not, is there some way of plugging in monitors into the computer that will consistently prevent this message from showing up? I believe I can obtain more monitors and cables to finish setting up the lab if I need to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can happen on Dells in particular if you have an add-on video card installed in a PCIe slot, but you're hooking the monitor up to the onboard video port, **OR** you are connecting the monitor using a DisplayPort -> VGA adapter.

The first scenario is most likely what you're running into.  If that's the case, you have a couple options:

- Hook the screen up to the the add-on card instead.  If it doesn't have a VGA port then get yourself a DVI cable or a DVI -> VGA adapter.  Both are really cheap.  Like $5 cheap.
- Remove the add-on video card from the PCIe slot.
- Change the BIOS setting you referenced earlier.  It should be under "Video" category.  It may give you a choice between "Auto" and "Intel HD Video" or "Onboard" and "Add-On Card".  It may also simply be a checkbox that says "Enable Multi-Display Support"

Note that the monitor probably has a built-in USB hub on it or maybe USB powered speakers.  That's what the USB cord is for.  But the USB cable has nothing to do with the video.

I recommend connecting the monitor via DVI to the add-on card.  First of all, somebody paid for that card so you may as well use it.  Also, VGA is ancient.  I don't know why we're still using it in 2014.  However, if this computer is for run-of-the-mill business use only, then removing the card is a perfectly acceptable solution.

Comment: I changed the BIOS settings and it worked, thanks.

Comment: Who wants to now, F2 is the key for entering the BIOS.

Comment: Not on Dell OptiPlex computers. The BIOS key is F12

Answer (score 2):

Solved problem in my Dell XPS 8700 – [It’s documented by Dell in their help pages](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN268373/setting-up-multiple-monitors-using-intel-multi-display-option-in-windows-8-for-xps-8700?lang=EN).

1. Went to BIOS
2. Went to “Advanced”
3. Scrolled down to “Onboard Device Configuration”
4. Pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Scrolled down to “Intel Multi-Display”
6. Pressed “Enabled”
7. Saved settings

And now I can again use my HDMI cable with my monitor.

Comment: This is a feature primarily available with sandy bridge intel or later processors with *on die* IGPs

Answer (score 1):

My solution was:

- press <kbd>F2</kbd>
- and then in the video option select the default option
- and then press <kbd>F2</kbd> again,
- then video option and the option to connect to 2 monitor and apply.

I hope that it works for somebody.

Comment: It seems BIOS settings